# MacBook with Windows keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mac, windows

Problem occurs when pressing the @ and the " keys.  They seem to be mapped to each other, so @ -> " and " -> @.
The system preferences allow modifier keys to be re-mapped but not these two.
Can it be done?

Comment: Normally this is just a matter of setting system prefs/keyboard/input sources to the layout which matches your hardware, probably "British PC" in your case.  Also there are others you can download and install if needed, such as http://liyang.hu/osx-british.xhtml

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like the main difference between a US and a UK keyboard. On a UK keyboard the " is above the number 2, and on a US keyboard the @ is above the 2.

Is the keyboard UK or US?

And is the Mac set to have a UK or a US keyboard attached?

Answer (score 2):

use [keyremap4macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/). It adds all these options and it's easy to add new mappings on your own - eg for media keys and so on. Also you can make the remaps device specific so a mac keyboard will work as usual.